# PHP: Getters and Setters

Tags: php, syntax

Recently I was setting up a symfony application where I've had to make some entitys. To create those Entitys I used the symfony console and ran the `make:entity` script.

This then asked me, if I want to add some fields. And of course I just added my Attributes using this function because it was easy to use. Then it automatically created my attributes with the matching doctrine Annotations and the getters and setters. Here's a small example:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254)
 */
private $attr1;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $attr2;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $attr3;

public function getAttr1(): ?string
{
    return $this->attr1;
}

public function setAttr1(string $attr1): self
{
    $this->attr1 = $attr1;
    return $this;
}

public function getAttr2(): ?int
{
    return $this->attr2;
}

public function setAttr2(int $attr2): self
{
    $this->attr2 = $attr2;
    return $this;
}

public function getAttr3(): ?bool
{
    return $this->attr3;
}

public function setAttr3(bool $attr3): self
{
    $this->attr3 = $attr3;
    return $this;
}
```

Now, my question is what those `?string || ?int ||?bool || self` mean. Do they like tell the function to expect to return a `string` and what does the `self` tells the function? I just got a little confused by this, because I've never seen such a thing in php untill now. (attention newbie-alert)

Comment: A quick look through the latest version of the PHP manual would give you the answer to this question

Comment: This is called `return type declaration` http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: This is a feature from php 7 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5
it's call type hint (introduced for performance)

Comment: relative to new feature of PHP7.1, type hints

Comment: Thanks @al! Those articles were very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to notice the output type of the method since php 7, you can get more informations [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

The `?` mean than the output type can be `null`, and the `self` is the same type of the current class.

Answer (score 1):

Those are parameters types (inputs and outputs).

- `?` - it allows to pass `null` to/from method.
- `self` - it means that method will return its object.

Answer (score 0):

Self means it return instace of this class. Its called "fluent setters". With that, you can chain-call methods. Eg:

```
$someObj->setId(1)
    ->setNum(5)
    ->setOtherAttr('string');
```